# Mongoose (MongoDB) removes directly after saving

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `mongoose` script that saves a user:

```
saveUser: function(username, password){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var newUser = new User({ username:username, password:password });
        newUser.save(function (err, msg) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve('User saved.' + msg);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This script seems to work, it calls the `resolve()` method and returns a saved user.

After that, however, my database does not show the record.

I call the function like this:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  user.saveUser(req.body.username, req.body.password)
      .then(function(msg){
        res.json({status: msg});
      }) 
      .catch(function(msg){
        res.json({status: msg});
      })
});
```

I've tried to find the record, and this is the result:

```
{
    "status": [
        {
            "_id": "56cec8a39641c8c01bd9f5e4",
            "username": "test",
            "password": "test",
            "born": "2016-02-25T09:25:55.425Z",
            "died": "2016-02-25T09:25:55.656Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

That is the only code relevant to the DB. Why does Mongoose remove the object right after creating it? I've never implemented a `remove` function?!

Comment: Mongoose doesn't remove an object after creating it, there's probably something going wrong in your code. Can you add the schema for `User` to your question, and also the query you used to find the record in the database. FWIW, Mongoose supports promises [out of the box](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), no need to wrap async methods (like `.save()` yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using `var newUser = new User({ username:username, password:password });`. You can instead use the following command to create your user in mongoose.

```
User.create({ username:username, password:password });
```